# "Unobstructed" Vision of Object

Tags: modeling

I have a small mesh inside a large mesh (i.e. sphere inside a cube) and would like to cut-out the (i.e.) cube in a way to automatically give "unobstructed vision" from the camera through the cube of the sphere (so all parts of the cube that hide parts of the sphere subtracted).

I tried to manually create the effect with a sphere inside a cube and a cylinder (but my real 3D meshes are a lot more complicated unfortunately, so doing it purely manually is not possible I think), and this is sort of the effect which I mean:

[image]

[image]

Of course, the "edges" of the cube are unnecessarily cut as they wouldn't obstruct the view. It took me quite some time do this by hand by creating a cylinder outside of the sphere, matching its angle with the camera angle and then subtracting it from the cube. Is there a fancy way to do it with raytracing or some other option?

Comment: When you don't want to lose the "feelings of 3D", does it mean you want everything to be shaded as if there was a cut-out in the cube? Light from the outside falling onto the sphere? Shadows of the cut-out borders from the cube falling onto the sphere?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want to make a cutout of the cube of everything that blocks the camera view of the sphere.